# Another string conversion URL utf8 java

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I've got String in java like this

> %C5%82%C3%B3

And I want to convert it to UTF-8. The output string should looks like this

> łó

How can I achieve that? I went through other similiar topics on SO but nothing helps. I've tried:

```
        byte[] b = myString.getBytes();
        byte[] b1 = myString.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
        byte[] b2 = myString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        byte[] b3 = myString.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2"));
        byte[] b4 = myString.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
        System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(new String(b, "ISO-8859-1"));
        System.out.println(new String(b1, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(new String(b1, "ISO-8859-1"));
        System.out.println(new String(b2, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(new String(b2, "ISO-8859-1"));
        System.out.println(new String(b3, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(new String(b3, "ISO-8859-1"));
        System.out.println(new String(b4, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(new String(b4, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

In above code myString contains

> %C5%82%C3%B3

and System.out always prints

> %C5%82%C3%B3

Any ideas or should I start writing my own conversion method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This String is URL-encoded. You need to decode it.

Make some tests here.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Then try this.

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode("%C5%82%C3%B3", "UTF-8");
```

See also:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me save a lot of time. I will accept it in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLDecoder class to decode your encoded String:

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("%C5%82%C3%B3", "UTF-8"));
```